# Opinion sought, jQuery: (an exercise) I want to join 5x seperate functions into 1x jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function

Code extract:
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/9AjfU/

The full code places `.tabs` and all the other elements inside an AJAX-filled jQuery UI modal, and it works perfectly.

Here I have each jQuery **slideUp()** the **div** s not associated with the **tab** you are hovering on and **slideDown()** the **div** s that do.

**I would like to know** what would be the best way to join all my **separate jQueries into one.**

The function `all()` exists because I have this in the jQuery UI modal dialog:

```
$('#your-dialog-id').dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
    $('.scroll-box').css({'max-height': bottomPosition-150, 'overflow-y': 'scroll'});
    all();}, //etc.
```

In each jQuery `.on("mouseover",` exists as the divs used to be added dynamically. **I haven't taken them away yet** as I plan on a full rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/9AjfU/2/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class='all'>all</li>
    <li class='musicselect'>music</li>
    <li class='sportselect'>sport</li>
    <li class='artsselect'>arts</li>
    <li class='generalselect'>general</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.tabs li').on("mouseover", function(){
    $('.general, .music, .sport, .arts').slideUp();
    $('.' + $(this).attr("class").replace("select", "") ).stop(true, true).slideDown();
    $('.tabs li').css('color', '#fff');
    $(this).css('color', '#66CBFF');
});
```

Comment: Your selector `$('div.' + $(this).attr("class").replace("select", "") )` had me scratching my head a few minutes. Very nice, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

try this, you can add helper id attributes to the `li` tags:

```
<ul>
    <li class='all'>all</li>
    <li id="music"    class='musicselect'>music</li>
    <li id="sport"    class='sportselect'>sport</li>
    <li id="arts"     class='artsselect'>arts</li>
    <li id="general"  class='generalselect'>general</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('ul li').on("mouseover", function(){
    $('div:not(.tabs)').slideUp();
    $('.' + this.id).stop(true, true).slideDown();
    $('.tabs li').css('color', '#fff'); // or $('.tabs li').addClass('white'); 
    $(this).css('color', '#66CBFF');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9AjfU/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the complete JavaScript code I came up with. This way you don't have to change your HTML at all.

```
$('.all').css('color', '#66CBFF');

$('div.tabs').on('mouseover', 'li', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $notTabs = $('div').not('.tabs'),
        className = e.target.className,
        tabClass = className.replace(/select/, '');

    $notTabs.not(tabClass).slideUp();
    if ($this.hasClass('all')){
        $notTabs.slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.' + tabClass).stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }
    $('div.tabs li').css('color', '#fff');
    $this.css('color', '#66CBFF');
});
```

You can see the sample here http://jsfiddle.net/g2xg7/1/

The thing you should keep in mind here is that this isn't going to work if you have to add classes to your `li` tab elements.